# Chemfig: \setarrowoffset has changed from texlive 2016 to 2020

Tags: beamer, errors, chemfig, chemistry, texlive-2016

I'm moving from a linux mint computer (texlive 2016) to a new one with texlive 2020.
I'm most interested in moving my chemistry lessons, written in beamer + chemfig, and I'm noticing some changes.
Please consider the following snippet:

```
   \onslide<7->{%\schemedebug{true}
    \schemestart 
    \chemfig{CO_{3}^{2-} + Ca^{2+}}
    \arrow(reag--prod){<=>}
    \chemfig{CaCO_{3}}
    % \setarrowoffset{8}
    \arrow(.south east--.north west)[90,0.05,]{}
    \schemestop
    \bigskip }
```

The problem is in the commented line `\setarrowoffset{8}` which works flawlessly in texlive 2016 while the following error is thrown in texlive 2020:

```
! Undefined control sequence.

\CF_compound ...hemfig {CaCO_{3}} \setarrowoffset{8pt}
 
l.720 \end{frame}
```

It's not a big deal - the precipitation down arrow sticks to CaCO_3 on texlive 2020, while it moves slightly to the right in the 2016 version - but I'm curious to learn a solution for the future.

Thanks to anyone who will find the time to help me.

EDIT: I'm afraid there's more than this. As I move to other lessons I'm finding more errors, like

! Undefined control sequence.
 \CF_currentstringangle

in another snippet I will not report.

Comment: As always on the site, please provide full minimal examples that others can test as is. None of the code you have shown is unuable by others as we have to guess the rest in order to even test the code. Going from TL16 to TL20 is also a big jump and packages are not always backwards compatible.

Comment: v1.3       2018/03/08 announced that setting of options should be done with `\setchemfig` and that all other `\set` command will get obsolete at some time. So check the documentation and adjust your document.